# Is it faster to return a value or modify a parameter passed by reference?

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

In a programme I am writing, I have to pass large data structures (images) between functions.  I need my code to be as fast as possible, on different OSs (thus, I can't profile all test cases).  I frequently have code of the form...

```
void foo() {
  ImageType img = getCustomImage();
}

ImageType getCustomImage() {
  ImageType custom_img;
  //lots of code
  return custom_img;
}
```

AFAIK, the line `ImageType img = getCustomImage();` will result in a copy constructor being called for `img` with the return value from `custom_img` as its parameter.  Wikipedia says that some compilers will even do this operation again, for an initial temporary variable!

My question:  Is it faster in general to thus bypass this overhead (copy constructors for images are expensive) by using pass by reference rather than a return value...

```
void foo() {
  ImageType img;
  getCustomImage(img);
}

void getCustomImage(ImageType &img) {
  //code operating directly on img
}
```

I've been told that if the compiler supports return value optimisation then there should be no difference.  Is this true? can I (within reason) assume this nowadays, and how should I structure my programmes when speed is important

Comment: Why have you tagged this C? With your mentions of copy constructors and your syntax for the pass by reference in the `getCustomImage` function signature, this is only applicable to C++.

Comment: Depending on your `ImageType` constructors, even without return value optimization, the two forms might be more or less equivalent.  This is why the only correct answer to "which is faster" is "profile."  If you can't do all platforms, pick your favorite... the major issues will likely be universally applicable.

Comment: To go off on a tangent, I'd say that a good approach that would sidestep all your worries is to review the definition of `ImageType`. If that class were to become a small, light-weight handler for dynamically managed storage (say a member `vector`), and if you use C++11 move semantics, then you could leave your code as it is (return by value) and you'd get good performance out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should write code that is maintainable, compilers are really good at doing the right thing for performance in most cases. If you feel that things go slowly, then measure the performance and after you have located the bottleneck, try to figure out how to improve it.

You are right in that *logically* the code triggers different copy constructions: from `custom_img` to the returned temporary and then to the `img` object in the caller code, but the fact is that both copies will be elided.

In the particular case of *return by value* versus *default-construct + pass-by-reference*, all calling conventions that I know of implement *return by value* by having the caller allocate the memory and pass a hidden pointer to the callee, which effectively implements what you would be trying to do. So from a performance point of view, they are basically equivalent.

I wrote about this (value semantics in function arguments and return values) in the past in this two blog entries:

- [Named Return Value Optimization](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html)
- [Copy Elision](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html)

**EDIT**: I have intentionally avoided the discussion of the cases where NRVO cannot be applied by the compiler, the reason being that any function `f` that can take a reference to the object for processing: `void f( T & out ) { /* code */ }` can be trivially convertible to a function where NRVO is trivial for the compiler to implement that returns by value by a simple transformation into: `T f() { T out; /* code */ return out; }`

Comment: Like you said, but nobody put it better than Donald Knuth: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I am not quite sure your quote supports exactly what David said, it's related, but... I expect programmers to identify their own "quirky" ideas as falling into the remaining 3%.

Comment: I would add that, most of the times, a "default constructed" object does not make sense. The constructor is supposed to initialize the class invariants, and as such most default constructors are errors of design (no better than null pointers: the infamous billion dollars mistake). When you're given an object, you expect it to be ready for use, that's the constructor contract. Default Constructors (like null pointers) break that contract. And without default constructor, this idiom of "out-parameters" is impossible (they become in/out).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: to continue that quote: "Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified."

Comment: @MatthieuM. completely agree, and not only that, but even in the cases where the default construction could make sense (think of a function that returns a vector of elements, an empty vector is a correctly fully built object), even in those cases, it complicates the code. The function does not control if the vector passed as reference is empty or not, so to comply with it's post conditions it should handle the non-empty case by clearing, which will require more code to maintain and to execute.

Answer (score 1):

since your images are big data structures, I would perhaps suggest that function should return pointers to images. You could use references also (which at the machine level are pointers), but I think pointers fit better for that purpose.

I am more familiar with C than with C++, so I could be wrong.

The important issue is when and by whom should your images be de-allocated.

Comment: If pointers are used, they need to be some sort of smart pointers.

Comment: Back to the original question, Qt is a C++ library with a QImage class.

Comment: @James: Because raw pointers invite leaks to dance on your code until it dies horribly.

Comment: @Matthieu M: I'm wondering about the 'need' part of the claim.

Comment: @James: I would say it's a blunt statement, and could be refined. However in practice raw pointers invite doubt: did the developer used a raw pointer because it does not own the resource, or did she forgot about our convention and in fact it does own the resource ? Systematically using a "smart" pointer (and having the dumb `pointer` class) allow to clearly document ownership in the code, not only its kind (when there is one) but also its absence.

Answer (score 1):

At least if you'r targeting reasonably current compilers for the reasonably typical OSes like Windows, MacOS, Linux, or *BSD, you can pretty well count on their implementing RVO/NRVO. IOW, you'd have to look pretty hard to find cases where there was enough difference to care about -- or most likely any at all.

Depending on how you're using the data involved, if there is a speed difference, it could just about as easily favor passing/return objects as using a reference. You might want to read David Abrahams's [article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) about this.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the question "What is faster?", I generally advise to actually measure for yourself, in your compiler / environment, and then to find out why is that so.