# Return value from function and performance

Tags: c, gcc

Consider these two `C` functions with different headers but the same body differing only in how they return their results (via stack or pointer): `T f1(int x)` and `void f2(int x, T *ret)` where `sizeof(T) >= 16`.
Is there any performance penalty when calling `f1` over calling `f2` or the compiler like `gcc -O2` optimizes both calls into the similar results.

Comment: Is the caller of `f2` supposed to hand it `ret` as a pointer to some already allocated, but just default-POD-constructed (i.e. uninitialised) place, or will there be some nontrivial constructor involved?

Comment: @leftaroundabout No constructors, preallocated space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it faster to return a value or modify a parameter passed by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997569/is-it-faster-to-return-a-value-or-modify-a-parameter-passed-by-reference)

Comment: @cha - It was tagged C++ a couple of minutes ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be a performance penalty from what I see. For f1, the function is going to have to create a object of type T, and then it's returning a copy of that since you didn't specify that it should be returned from reference or pointer (but then the function would have to allocate memory for it).

But as for f2, you are sending an object of type T that you have already allocated memory for. This saves time because the function doesn't have to create a new object or allocate memory for it.

Though I'm not sure if using gcc level 2 optimization uses RVO to avoid copying the object as a return type.

Comment: I am not sure. Because allocating `T` in `f1` on stack is done only by changing the "stackpointer".

Comment: Move semantics in C++11 make crazy things like that optimal *in* *the* *language*.

Comment: @cha0site No C++ please. We are in plain C.

Comment: @James: Sorry, missed that. I saw `T` and thought this was a C++ template.